# Comparing modifiers in Java

Tags: java, reflection, modifiers

In java you can use reflection to get an integer representing all the modifiers on a class. For example:

```
public final class Foo{}
Foo.getClass().getModifiers();//returns 17 because public=1 and final=16
```

My question is, what is the best way to compare the modifiers of two classes? Lets say we have another class:

```
private class Bar{}
Bar.getClass().getModifiers();//returns 2 because private=2
```

Now the simple way would be to have a ton of ifs saying modifier.isAbstract, modifier.isPublic, etc. But is there a cleaner way to do this?

Edit: In the end I want two lists. One says what Foo has that Bar doesn't, and the other one says what Bar has that Foo doesn't. So in this particular case I want:

```
FooHasBarDoesnt: public, final
BarHasFooDoesnt: private
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the [`Modifier.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#toString%28int%29) method?

> Return a string describing the access modifier flags in the specified modifier.

e.g.

```
List<String> modNames = Arrays.asList(Modifier.toString(mods).split("\\s"));
```

This list looks like - `[public, final]`.

Comment: Totally forgot about the `toString()`. You are right, this is just what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As it is int with flags you can compare them by bit operations.

```
int common = flags1 & flags2;
int only1 = flags1 ^ common;
int only2 = flags2 ^ common;
```

Then you can query `only1` and `only2` by `Modifier` methods.

Comment: The problem is that I still wont know what exactly the modifiers are and will have to call all the `Modifier.isWhatever` functions. I think thought that I am just beating around the bush, I dont think there is a way around that.