# 270+ Modifiers attached to Object Methods in Java Reflection

Tags: java

I am learning Java Reflection, and wass playing around with the `java.lang.Reflection` class. Here is the code I wrote in a class called `Driver`

```
Method[] method = Dummy.class.getMethods();

System.out.println("MEthods");
    for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + method[i].getName());
        System.out.println("Declaring Class: " + method[i].getDeclaringClass());
        System.out.println("ToGenericString: " + method[i].toGenericString());
        System.out.println("Modifiers: " + method[i].getModifiers());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Here is the Dummy class

```
public class Dummy {
    public int b(){return 0;}
}
```

I would get output like the following

```
Name: b
Declaring Class: class Dummy
ToGenericString: public int Dummy.b()
Modifiers: 1

Name: hashCode
Declaring Class: class java.lang.Object
ToGenericString: public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
Modifiers: 257

Name: notifyAll
Declaring Class: class java.lang.Object
ToGenericString: public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll()
Modifiers: 273

//etc
```

**My question is:**
Why do the Object inherited methods such as `wait()`, `notify()` `hashcode()` etc have over 270+ modifiers whereas my ethod `b()` only has 1, interestingly enough `toString()` also has 1

Comment: Read the documentation of `getModifiers()`, it is not a number, its a code (a bitset in particular). `hashcode`  is native (256) and public (1) resulting in 257. `toString` has only public (1) resulting in 1, `notify` is public, native, final (16), giving 273. The values/constants are documented in `java.reflect.Modifier`.

Comment: @CoronA I suggest you make your Comment an Answer so that it can be accepted to close this Question.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Comparing modifiers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199409/comparing-modifiers-in-java)

Comment: @CoronA sweet thanks, would've never have guessed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `getModifiers` is not a number but a code (a bitset in particular).

Each modifier has a value, e.g.:
- public is 1
- final is 16
- native is 256

You have to combine them with the bitwise or operation (which is in this case similar to the add operation).

To get a complete list of modifiers read the documentation and the source code of [Modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html).

- toString is public (1) => 1
- hashcode is public (1) and native (256) => 257
- notifyAll is public (1) and final (16) and native (256) => 273